# using git on windows and push changes to linux debian 6

Tags: javascript, git, node.js, github

My notebook has Windows 7 64bit and I can make changes and commit perfectly.

I have a repo on my cloud server and I push changes from my notebook to the cloud repo.

Then I created a bare repo to deploy my apps. The bare repository has the nodejs app. I have to recompile bcrypt because bcrypt the cloud repository has bcrypt for windows 7,

I push from my notebook to the cloud repo, and then i pull from the cloud repo to the bare repository. The bare repository has the deploy app.

The problem is that sometimes the precompilers from nodejs change the bare repository. So if I don’t commit the changes the bare repo gives me an error and says that i have to commit or add the new files.

So I use

```
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
```

and I pull the changes from the cloud server repository.

I solved the first problem, but I have a second problem... when i pull the changes from the cloud repo to the bare repository, i have to re-compile the node-modules because the pull replace the node-module changes.

I don’t want to recompile the node-modules every time that I have to pull changes. Is there any way to merge a version?

Comment: You can replace bcrypt with https://github.com/shaneGirish/bcrypt-nodejs. bcrypt-nodejs is a native javascript module which does not require compilation

Comment: i have many modules more, like mongoskin or other, i want to know how to merge versions without recompile modules

Comment: you can ignore the node_modules folder via a .gitignore file in your git repo, then in your node.js startup script you can execute npm install

Answer (score 1):

1. The correct command to remove all the changes in the working dir is `git reset --hard`.
2. You should not keep compiled code in your repo. Add the output of the compilation to your `.gitignore` and compile on your systems after checkout.